# Given positions find the symmetry group

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups, algorithms

Given a finite set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n=2,3$),
is there any algorithm to find its symmetry group?
For example, if the input is {(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)}, then the output is the dihedral group of eight elements.
Any reference could be helpfull for me.

Comment: It's an interesting question. Can I just check if you are wanting your symmetries to be linear? For instance, if the vectors in your example were all translated up $1$, would you want the algorithm to spit out the trivial group or the dihedral group of eight elements?

Comment: Put another way, you are asking for the setwise-stabilizer of a bunch of vectors, but to understand the question we need to know what group you are sitting inside. So, my earlier comment was to check whether you are thinking inside $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ or $AGL(n,\mathbb{R})$. However, equally, perhaps you are really working inside $O(n)$ (i.e. rotations/ reflections) or $E(n)$ (rigid transformations). Once you know what group you are in, the algorithm you are seeking will consist of examining certain cosets of subgroups and checking intersections.

Comment: A discussion of algorithms which calculate setwise-stabilizers, you could look at this thesis: http://www.math.uni-rostock.de/~rehn/docs/diploma-thesis-cs-rehn.pdf

Comment: I presume you are looking for symmetries which preserve the distance between any pair of vectors.

Comment: Yes, I want that symmetries to be linear. And I dont want translations groups. And, Yes I am also looking for symmetries which preserve the distance between any pair of vectors.

Comment: OK, in that case, the group you are working inside is $O(n)$. Your question is asking for an algorithm to calculate the setwise-stabilizer in $O(n)$ of some bunch of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The link I gave above describes such algorithms in general. For $n=2$, the group $O(2)$ is particularly simple -- it is a degree 2 extension of the circle group, so all subgroups are cyclic or dihedral, and so finding a setwise stabilizer is simply a matter of grouping your set of vectors so that they all have the same norm, and then checking angles between them.

Comment: In principle the same would work for $n=3$, but there are a few more subgroups to be aware of (e.g. for the finite ones, you need to account for platonic solids). See here for some stuff to get you started:  https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_subgroups_of_SO(3,R)